# notepad++ как сделать табуляцию в виде стрелок?

Tags: notepad++

notepad++ как сделать табуляцию в виде стрелок ?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста вопрос. Непонятно, что имеется ввиду.

Comment: @MindCleaner видимо чтобы отображалась в виде стрелки, как в Ворде.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_c6X1QHjves

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь меню

```
Вид - Отображение символов - Отображать Пробелы и Табуляции
```

или в английской версии

```
View - Show symbol - Show Whitespace and TAB
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]